# Getting the selected string in the dropdown list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

To begin with, I am an absolute beginner in front-end development, thus please excuse me if the question is too elementary.

The project I am working on, a drop-down list has been defined as:

```
<div ng-controller="FacetController">
    <div class="spnlocationdrop-container" ng-hide="isservicelocal">
        <select class="spnlocationdrop" ng-model="$parent.locationsearch" ng-options="location for location in locations | sortArray ">
            <option value="">All Cities</option>
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

The list contains cities, out-of which the user has to select one. The value has to be stored, and sent to the backend via an AJAX call.

How do I get the selected value? Until now, I've been doing that using the **`document.getElementByID().value()`** function, but since the above list contains no `ID`, how do I get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model` will have the value of the option selected.

Here's a simple working example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UWFBVNEbzPuviIUxffgH?p=preview)

In my example, `data.singleSelect` has the value you need so I'm able to output that to the view using `{{ data.singleSelect }}` though if I wanted to access it in my controller I would do `var input = $scope.data.singleSelect` and then pass that `input` variable to the backend via an AJAX call.

Comment: When I use it in another JS file, it shows "undefined".

Comment: What do you mean by "another JS file"? You won't be able to access that variable if the other file (which I'm assuming is another controller) doesn't have access to that scope.

Comment: It has the access. I am trying-out the solution you gave, will update in a sec.